# [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]

Tags: java, spring

I have added one more  class as UserDetails.java to my entity package. I have added all the necessary Controller and DAO classes to respective package. But I am using a single Service class for both the entities. Now, when I run service for  earlier  entity class, it works fine. But when I run service for entity class I added later I gives error message.

May 20, 2020 12:20:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/TwoFactor] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException

at com.firstapp129.twofactor.service.DistScannerServiceImpl.getUsers(DistScannerServiceImpl.java:39)

I am using the following Service Class Code:

```
package com.firstapp129.twofactor.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.firstapp129.twofactor.dao.DistScannerDAO;
import com.firstapp129.twofactor.dao.UserDetailsDAO;
import com.firstapp129.twofactor.entity.DistScanner;
import com.firstapp129.twofactor.entity.UserDetails;

@Service
public class DistScannerServiceImpl implements DistScannerService {

    @Autowired
    private DistScannerDAO distScannerDAO;
    private UserDetailsDAO userDetailsDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<DistScanner> getCustomers() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return distScannerDAO.getCustomers();
    }
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveDistScanner(DistScanner theDistScanner) {
        distScannerDAO.saveDistScanner(theDistScanner);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<UserDetails> getUsers() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return userDetailsDAO.getUsers();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveUserDetails(UserDetails theUserDetails) {

        userDetailsDAO.saveUserDetails(theUserDetails);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Field userDetailsDAO is null. Reason is missing @Autowired annotation.

Answer (score 0):

The UserDetailsDAO is not autowired hence throws null pointer exception.\
Add @Autowired annotation on top of it.